# Create a double border between thead and tbody

Tags: css, html-table

I made a test about a border to separate `thead` and `tbody`, but the `thead` seems to have a priority on the `tbody`.

If you have an idea…

- Here is my test: http://jsfiddle.net/cFKns/2/
- Search to do this: http://img844.imageshack.us/img844/693/12293655.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `border-collapse` value to `separate` on the portions you don't want the border overlapping, then set the `border-spacing` to 1px on the side the borders will touch.

I also had to move the border definitions to the `TH` and `TD` tags, as I don't think `border-collapse` and `border-spacing` apply to `thead` and `tbody` (at least it didn't work when I tried).

You can see the updated results with my findings here: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/Pf7My/1/

I targeted the first set of `td` tags by using `tr:first-child td`.  The makes sure only the top row as a black top border.